# How to display thumbnail only for first post in the category

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to display post thumbnail only for the first post in my categories archive in Wordpress. Next posts are supposed to show only the title, no thumbnail.

How do I achieve that? Is there any plugin to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Create the variable on which showing the post thumbnail is going to depend before your `WP_Query()` in `archive-category.php`, and change it's value to falsy in the end like:

```
<?php 
$counter = 1;
$query = new WP_Query(/* category $arguments here */);
while($query->$have_posts) {
  $query->the_post();
  if ($counter) the_post_thumbnail()

  // rest of operations 

  $counter = 0;
}
```

Comment: have any plugin ? i want to use it in wp wideget

Comment: You can the same thing in the specific widget, but it is not what your question is about, as the category page is not the widget. I cannot think of writing plugin to achieve something this simple, unless you don't really ask about coding.

Comment: <?php $recent = new WP_Query(); ?>
<?php $recent->query( 'cat=1&showposts=5' ); ?>
<?php $is_first_post = true; ?>

<?php while( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
    <ul>
        <li>
  
  <?php 
                if ( $is_first_post  && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail(); 
                    $is_first_post = false; 
                }
                ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>

                </li>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: i got a code like it. now want to use this  in widget using shortcode. i it possible?